# ‘In’ or ‘On’ the earth (Hebrew) - Genesis 6:5

Tags: hebrew, genesis, translation-philosophy, hebrew-bible

It interesting to observe בארץ being translated by different English (and non English) translations as either *in the earth* or *on the earth*.

This is not limited to this verse by any means.

> “The Lord saw that the wickedness of man was great **in the earth**, and that every intention of the thoughts of his heart was only evil continually.”
>   ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭6:5‬ ‭ESV‬‬

Most likely* the Biblical cosmology of an enclosed flat-earth covered by an impenetrable firmament at the time, it doesn’t seem unreasonable to use ‘*in*’ the earth and at the same time not make all earth dwellers cave dweller or living subterraineously. They were living in the earth terrarium.

What is the correct rendering in Hebrew of בארץ (I would argue for in the earth) and should it be changed even if it doesn’t align to secular scientific cosmology?

*requested rewording of the question

Comment: "Given Biblical cosmology of an enclosed flat-earth covered by an impenetrable firmament at the time" Such is not inarguably the 'Biblical cosmology,' and as such should not be presupposed as a help in understanding the phrase "'ב' the earth."

Comment: I don’t intend to turn this into a flat earth discussion. Ancient civilizations all had a flat earth dome covering type cosmology. The spherical ball earth is a relatively new concept accepted ~500 years ago and while some Greek philosophers attempted to suggest a ball earth (philosophically and hypothetically) it did not stick as it did in the last 500 years onwards. I’m not presupposing, I’m offering an interpretation for the IN alternative being possible and most likely. I’m not asking you to agree to the Biblical cosmology, which is invariably undeniable from Scripture.

Comment: Also, if I presuppose the earth is a globe then my language will reflect as much; similarly if the ancients presupposed a flat earth with a firmament cover then the language will reflect as much. So I don’t accept your implied premise that it’s irrelevant or unnecessary. Proper exegesis requires good hermeneutics and imposing modern views on the ancients’ texts, skews the meaning and syntax. I’m trying to be cognizant of the ancients’ worldview to get a most accurate translation/interpretation. Even if it’s highly controversial I can handle exploring/balancing multiple cosmologies just fine.

Comment: I'm saying don't presuppose either. The ancient world wasn't monolithic; and a round earth is not a 'modern' idea besides. The idea that 'everyone' believed in a flat earth in the ancient world is bogus anyway; and even if 'most' did, this could not be assumed for the Hebrews as you have here. My suggestion that you not include a presupposition in your question which has not been demonstrated is not a 'premise,' it's just common sense. If you want the real truth of a matter, you should always eliminate assumptions, because they will affect the outcome of the data observation.

Comment: Your response is begging for an avalanche flatearth Bible verses but I’ll refrain by editing the question to say most likely as opposed to given. This despite an overwhelming archeological consensus It is true that the cultures did not agree on the details but in general it had the same common theme. What other cosmology are you aware of in Hebrew archeology? I think it’s a reasonable compromise. The implication of the translation colors the interpretation regardless the cosmology. Your desire to remove it by design tilts the scales in your favor against the facts, by no means is it’s unbiased

Comment: I read from you Christianity SE that you are Catholic and I remembered a speech I listened to by Guy Consulmago from 2008 long before the flat earth debate. I can’t say he speaks for all Catholics but he certainly admits that this is the Biblical consensus as a Catholic scholar of the Bible. I can’t find his full speech any more online, it has been deleted but interestingly I found an excerpt from the speech a little way into the clip he addresses the Biblical Cosmolgy https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xYP3nK4XfOk

Comment: You didn't find anything slightly odd from this 'priest,' or should I say, 'Top Vatican Jesuit Astronomer,' (sic.) who claims among other basic truisms, "It’s NOT the Jews, It’s the Jesuits!"? LOL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89633/discussion-between-autodidact-and-sola-gratia).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Autodidact
The correct rendering in modern English is "on the earth" or "upon the earth". If you have Logos Bible Software or if you go to biblegateway.com, you can search for all English translations about Gen 6.5. When I do this search, I can see that most English translations and revisions that use "in the earth" are King James Bible translations, editions and revisions. Most modern translations have "on the earth". The two most recent translations, such as the Lexham English Bible (LEB) and the International Standard Version (ISV) use "upon the earth" and "throughout the earth" respectively.
None of this, however, bears upon the understanding of flat-earth vs round-earth debate. Not one bit. Even in English, one could use "on," "in," "upon," "through," in various ways to basically mean the same thing. Prepositions in Hebrew do not have a one-to-one correspondence in English, and even then, English is flexible.
So, again, to answer your question: "on the earth" is preferable, but "in," "upon," or "throughout" are not incorrect either.

Comment: Yes that is the modern English but what’s the ancient Hebrew original? It’s in the earth. It’s no secret that Biblical cosmolgy is flat earth. So the language will reflect as much. It seems that a modern paradigm has been used to reinterpret what the Hebrew language actually says in favor of secular science rather than textual integrity. Thank you for your response +1 and welcome. Click on the tour link at the bottom of this page to familiarize yourself with the site and expectations.

Comment: @Autodidact......thank you for your recognition. However, your comment that " Yes that is the modern English but what’s the ancient Hebrew original? It’s in the earth " does not follow. The Hebrew is בארץ but there is no one-to-one correspondence in English. It's not my opinion that בארץ and the like in Hebrew can variously mean "on" or "in" or either in different passages. As much as we use different prepositions in English to mean the same thing in the same contexts, the same happens in Hebrew and Greek.

Comment: I dont have time to produce extensive exemplary evidence right now. But, you may review scholarly resources on this matter and you will see that (1) Hebrew and English dont work that way, and (2) none of this bears with the flat-earth debate. By number (2), Im not denying the biblical text reflects a flat earth, I know it does. The Bible is not scientific at all. It reflects ancient Near Eastern and greco-roman worldviews--including a flat earth. This is well-known in scholarship. But, again, the preposition itself doesnt prove anything in relation to the flat-earth debate.

Comment: I’m not interested in the flat earth. I’m interested in whether it says in or on. And the ב in the word בארץ is used for in. I already know it’s in. Prove that it’s on like the English have mistranslated it. You can’t because the Hebrew says it’s in, that’s probably why this question has not been touched with a ten foot pole because it does show that Biblical cosmology is reflected in its wording to be flat earth. It’s undeniable the Bible describes the earth as flat.

Comment: @Autodidact....---- Hebrew and English do not work that way. If you take the years to study linguistics and semantics and study word fallacies, you will see that prepositions do not work this way. It's well documented in grammars and linguistic resources with examples that prepositions do not prove much when it comes to these kinds of issues. It's the background and the contexts that you need to pay attention to. Yes, the biblical text reflects a flat-earth--although it's not scientifically flat. But, this is neither proved nor disproved by word prepositions. Understood?

Comment: Im not going to reproduce books on linguistics and semantics here.

Comment: I didn’t ask for books, I asked for a literal, non interpreted, original context, translation of בארץ into English. That’s all.

Comment: Ancient texts must be interpreted, unfortunately--even if they would have been written in KJV English. Context is king, not words or prepositions in isolation. Flat earth is textually proved by paying attention to what the biblical authors say about cosmology: pillars of the earth, circle of the earth, solid dome or sky that covers the earth, tall mountains that touch the sky, the Table of Nations in Gen 10 is limited to the ancient Near East, etc...

Comment: @Autodidact the 'literal translation' of a preposition does not exist. Even more than with content words, function words don't map one-to-one to words in another language.

Comment: I agree @keelan I agree but you can still convey a meaning from one language to another. For instance in Russian the color blue has a separate word for light blue and for dark blue. But yet I was able to convey in English translation that the blue is lighter or darker without having to literally use a word that doesn’t exist in English because in English it’s just blue. You’re saying that it’s content dependent in Hebrew which makes my point, the word would mean inside the physical ground or in the terrarium earth. It makes a difference if you impose modern thinking on the interpretation, yes?

Comment: @Autodidact.....your comment about the color blue doesn't really answer the issue at hand, however. You might be right about that point in particular, but it doesn't correctly address the usage prepositions in Hebrew and English. For example, in English you can use "in" and "on" in various ways that are not literal, just like in Hebrew (by the way): " This engine runs on gas. " What does "on gas" means here? You see? It means : " This engine functions by using gasoline. " Understood?

Comment: @Autodidact.....Read  my past professor, Dr. Micheal S. Heiser here on the beth preposition in Hebrew, especially the section " The Meaning of the Image of God ": --- http://drmsh.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Image-of-God-LBD.pdf

Comment: בבית **In the house** Genesis 27:15, 39:2,8,9 Judges 17:12 and so on but when it comes to **on the house** translations in English בית , 1 1Kings 7:20, 51 or why not use **upon** על 1Kings 21:29. But even so if what you say means we cannot determine from the text whether it’s in or on, even though it’s always translated “in the” when it’s written that way, context  would be critical and by no means did they have the current cosmology in mind. So I guess the modern translators took the liberty to impose a modern scientific cosmology on the ancient text which changes the Biblical cosmology

Comment: @Autodidact.....Ok, I see. But, your examples are not examples that show nuances or ambiguities. That's the problem. Therefore, you think that it always works that way including, in this case, "in the earth" vs "on the earth." But, that's not necessarily so. So, all Im telling you is do not put too much weight on this, it's a can of worms. It's wrong to accuse -- in this particular case -- translators of mistranslating בארץ. For example, the Hebrew for sky is actually not an expanse (like some modern translations do), but actually a solid dome. But, oh well. We understand.

Answer (score 0):

1On another day, the sons of God came to present themselves before the LORD; and Satan also came with them to present himself before Him. 2“Where have you come from?” said the LORD to Satan. “From roaming through the earth,” he replied, “and from walking back and forth in it.”

There were many ancient underground cities... there are many recently discovered and not yet discovered...
And there are many many brand new underground cities and facilities.
As it seems useful to hide things now... it was since the beginning.

16And they said to the mountains and the rocks, “Fall on us and hide us from the face of the One seated on the throne, and from the wrath of the Lamb. 17For the great day of Their wrath has come, and who is able to withstand it?”…

Comment: משׁוט Is going to and fro. I don’t see the word through represented in the Hebrew. But that would have been a great passage to compare and contrast. I suppose if מנּי were used it could mean through but through how? Literally through the soil or through regions?